# Realm Crashes, Providing No Explanation at All

Tags: realm

I had a project that was using CoreData. Ported it to use Realm. Including rewriting a bunch of tests and the creation of sample data.

Went to run it, soon as I do Realm() anywhere I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

Of course I was thinking that maybe I should:

- delete the app from the simulator
- remove the realm file

Did those things, still crashing. The strange thing is, it seems that the query has returned some results, then it crashes.

My main issue at this point is maybe because this is written in C++ this is a symptom or wrapper-itis: where the syntactical advantages of wrapping something are rapidly undone by the fact that there is poor to no useful error reporting.

I can't even run a test right now because the simulator crashes on startup.

Question is simple: what else can you do besides delete the app and the realm file? The only thing I am doing in the code that is causing a crash is:

1. instantiating the Realm
2. asking for all of a given object()
3. checking to see if the count of the results is > 0

How does that result in a bad access?

#### Update

I commented out all Realm code in the app so the simulator would start then moved back to trying to run tests. I am using the RealmEnabledTestCase which makes an in memory instance, then running the absolute simplest test possible: create a single object with a few properties then save it. Crashes with a bad access.

As for the question of what it's doing, here is the symbol trace:

[image: nice clear explanation!]

The configuration of the realm instance is done in the test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had an unsupported type on one of the attributes. Of course, this could never happen in core data because it generates the Managed Object classes. What a waste of time. This has great potential, but it's completely nuts that it can't parse the schema and output error messages for things that are unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

JP from Realm here.

Some generally useful things to do (even without Realm) to troubleshoot `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors would be to look for hints of what's being dereferenced in the stack trace, or to run with Address Sanitizer or zombies enabled. There are a few SO posts that walk through some debugging tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25144840/373262) and on raywenderlich.com [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1).

As of what could be happening in your specific case, it's hard to tell because you haven't exactly shared any code or steps for us to reproduce. I encourage you to file a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new) so we can help troubleshoot with you. We always try to be as responsive as possible.

Finally, the fact that Realm's core is written in C++ and wrapped in Objective-C has no bearing whatsoever on the ability to print a useful error message when dereferencing a null pointer or accessing an invalid memory address. All errors that occur in Realm's C++ core are either reported as assertions with a message logged to STDOUT, or exposed as Objective-C exceptions containing a descriptive message.

Comment: I am probably going back to CoreData. Seriously, in my programming 10 commandments, thou shalt not propagate useless error messages is in the #1 spot. Was pretty excited about it. Not so much anymore. If the last part of your message is true, why am I seeing no messages in the console that are telling me anything about what is wrong? We are going all the way to the app terminating without a whisper.

Comment: I'm afraid things won't be any different with Core Data when it comes to expecting an error message when dereferencing a null pointer or an invalid memory address.

Comment: Using Swift I don't waste time on NPEs anymore.